# Decimal point in secondary Y axis and integer value in primary Y axis in fusion chart

Tags: fusioncharts

How to create dual axis with primary Y axis having integer value and secondary Y axis has decimal point in fusion chart. Below is my current code that is showing both axis as decimal point values.

```
<graph animation='0' PYAxisName='Units' SYAxisName='PPB' bgColor='f5f5f5' rotateNames='1' PYAxisMaxValue='" + maxYVal + "'  SYAxisMaxValue='" + maxY1Val + "' canvasBorderColor='cccccc' canvasBorderThickness='0' canvasBgAlpha='100' showColumnShadow='0' showvalues='0' formatNumberScale='1' anchorSides='10' anchorRadius='3'  decimalPrecision='1' showShadow='0' showDivLineValue='1' numdivlines='" + numLines + "' divlinecolor='DCDCDC' divLineThickness='1'>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using FusionCharts v 3.12.2, it is possible to get the secondary y-axis value in decimal by setting "sForceDecimals" attribute at chart attribute level. Refer to the code below:

```js
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
    var revenueChart = new FusionCharts({
        type: 'stackedcolumn3dlinedy',
        renderAt: 'chart-container',
        width: '550',
        height: '350',
        dataFormat: 'json',
        dataSource: {
            "chart": {
                "caption": "Product-wise Quarterly Revenue vs. Profit %",
                "subCaption": "Harry's SuperMart - Last Year",
                "xAxisname": "Quarter",
                "pYAxisName": "Sales",
                "sYAxisName": "Profit %",
                "numberPrefix": "$",
                "sNumberSuffix": "%",
                //This "sForceDecimals" attribute will make only the secondary y-axis values in decimals.
                "sForceDecimals": "1",
                "sYAxisMaxValue": "25",
                "paletteColors": "#0075c2,#1aaf5d,#f2c500",
                "bgColor": "#ffffff",
                "borderAlpha": "20",
                "showCanvasBorder": "0",
                "usePlotGradientColor": "0",
                "plotBorderAlpha": "10",
                "legendBorderAlpha": "0",
                "legendShadow": "0",
                "legendBgAlpha": "0",
                "valueFontColor": "#ffffff",
                "showXAxisLine": "1",
                "xAxisLineColor": "#999999",
                "divlineColor": "#999999",
                "divLineIsDashed": "1",
                "showAlternateHGridColor": "0",
                "subcaptionFontBold": "0",
                "subcaptionFontSize": "14",
                "showHoverEffect": "1"
            },
            "categories": [{
                "category": [{
                    "label": "Q1"
                }, {
                    "label": "Q2"
                }, {
                    "label": "Q3"
                }, {
                    "label": "Q4"
                }]
            }],
            "dataset": [{
                "seriesname": "Food Products",
                "data": [{
                    "value": "11000"
                }, {
                    "value": "15000"
                }, {
                    "value": "13500"
                }, {
                    "value": "15000"
                }]
            }, {
                "seriesname": "Non-Food Products",
                "data": [{
                    "value": "11400"
                }, {
                    "value": "14800"
                }, {
                    "value": "8300"
                }, {
                    "value": "11800"
                }]
            }, {
                "seriesname": "Profit %",
                "renderAs": "line",
                "parentYAxis": "S",
                "showValues": "0",
                "data": [{
                    "value": "14"
                }, {
                    "value": "16"
                }, {
                    "value": "15"
                }, {
                    "value": "17"
                }]
            }]
        }
    }).render();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://static.fusioncharts.com/code/latest/fusioncharts.js"></script>
<div id="chart-container">FusionCharts will render here</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing with below code -

```
FusionCharts.ready(function() {
  var salesChart = new FusionCharts({
      type: 'mscombidy2d',
      renderAt: 'chart-container',
      width: '500',
      height: '300',
      dataFormat: 'json',
      dataSource: {
        "chart": {
          "caption": "Revenues and Profits",
          "subCaption": "For last year",
          "xAxisname": "Month",
          "pYAxisName": "Amount (In USD)",
          "sYAxisName": "Profit",
          "numberPrefix": "$",
          "sYAxisMaxValue": "50",
          //Primary Y-Axis Name font properties
          "pYAxisNameFont": "Arial",
          "pYAxisNameFontSize": "12",
          "pYAxisNameFontColor": "#003366",
          "pYAxisNameFontBold": "1",
          "pYAxisNameFontItalic": "1",
          "pYAxisNameAlpha": "50",
          //Secondary Y-Axis Name font properties
          "sYAxisNameFont": "Arial",
          "sYAxisNameFontSize": "12",
          "sYAxisNameFontColor": "#003366",
          "sYAxisNameFontBold": "1",
          "sYAxisNameFontItalic": "1",
          "sYAxisNameAlpha": "50",
          "theme": "fusion"
        },
        "categories": [{
          "category": [{
            "label": "Jan"
          }, {
            "label": "Feb"
          }, {
            "label": "Mar"
          }, {
            "label": "Apr"
          }, {
            "label": "May"
          }, {
            "label": "Jun"
          }, {
            "label": "Jul"
          }, {
            "label": "Aug"
          }, {
            "label": "Sep"
          }, {
            "label": "Oct"
          }, {
            "label": "Nov"
          }, {
            "label": "Dec"
          }]
        }],
        "dataset": [{
          "seriesName": "Revenues",
          "data": [{
            "value": "16000"
          }, {
            "value": "20000"
          }, {
            "value": "18000"
          }, {
            "value": "19000"
          }, {
            "value": "15000"
          }, {
            "value": "21000"
          }, {
            "value": "16000"
          }, {
            "value": "20000"
          }, {
            "value": "17000"
          }, {
            "value": "22000"
          }, {
            "value": "19000"
          }, {
            "value": "23000"
          }]
        }, {
          "seriesName": "Profits",
          "renderAs": "area",
          "showValues": "0",
          "data": [{
            "value": "4000"
          }, {
            "value": "5000"
          }, {
            "value": "3000"
          }, {
            "value": "4000"
          }, {
            "value": "1000"
          }, {
            "value": "7000"
          }, {
            "value": "1000"
          }, {
            "value": "4000"
          }, {
            "value": "1000"
          }, {
            "value": "8000"
          }, {
            "value": "2000"
          }, {
            "value": "7000"
          }]
        }, {
          "seriesName": "Profit %age",
          "parentYAxis": "S",
          "renderAs": "line",
          "showValues": "0",
          "data": [{
            "value": "25"
          }, {
            "value": "25"
          }, {
            "value": "16.66"
          }, {
            "value": "21.05"
          }, {
            "value": "6.66"
          }, {
            "value": "33.33"
          }, {
            "value": "6.25"
          }, {
            "value": "25"
          }, {
            "value": "5.88"
          }, {
            "value": "36.36"
          }, {
            "value": "10.52"
          }, {
            "value": "30.43"
          }]
        }]
      }
    })
    .render();
});
```

To know more about this feature please refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/features/axis-and-gridlines#secondary-axis

Here is the demo fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/qpws0yan/

Also refer - https://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/chart-guide/chart-configurations/axes#configure-font-properties-for-y-axis-names